# Catching Exception in API to handle all possible exceptions occuring in implementation?

Tags: java, exception

Let say I have 2 projects A (API), and B (implementation).
My sonar-lint tells me I should never throw Exception because it is too generic. So, what should be the proper way to handle any kinds of exceptions in the API, including both runtime and "checked" exceptions ?

Project A

```
public interface IBuilder {
    public void create() throws Exception;
}
```

Project B

```
public abstract class ABuilder implements IBuilder {
    public void create() throws Exception {
        throw myImplException();
    }
}

public class ARealBuilder extends ABuilder {
    public void create() throws Exception {
        //Some Exceptions and RunTimeExceptions can occurs
    }
}
```

If I create my own exception type like this:

```
public class myException extends Exception {
}
```

Does this handle RuntimeExceptions ?

Comment: Hard to say, since you don't show us the code handling the exceptions. What does the catch block look like?

Comment: It is up to the user of project A to catch the exceptions the way he wants. If you wants to know the kind of exceptions that can occur, it it basically common exceptions such as NullPointerException or failed Http request (Error 500 for example).

Answer (score 0):

Just my two cents, but as I started typing it in a comment it became too long:

- Throwing `Exception` doesn't provide any useful information, what do you do in the catch part of your API method? You always have to handle all exceptions and/or re-throw them.
- The proper way of handling exceptions has to be done in the implementation part (Project B):

  - Is the information not useful or can/should be handled Project B? Handle it (via a retry mechanism or providing a meaningful default value, e.g. user not found in session => return an `UnknownUser` object or `null`).
  - Is the information useful for Project A? Define a project specific exception, e.g. `UserNotFoundException` and throw that one. Then Project A can handle that specific case.
- You don't need to define the RuntimeExceptions as they are bubbling up the call stack until Project A anyway (if not handled/catched before in Project B), but yes they are also children of `Exception`.